# Class cast exception on setting name

Tags: java

I am getting a cast exception while setting the name.

```
    Object[] customers= customerRepository.getCustomerName(Id);     
    Customer row = new Customer();          
    row.setName((String) customers[0]+" "+(String) customers[1]);
```

The exception is:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
 nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
 [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: How bout instead of doing the String typecast just do .toString() ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be better to use `customers[0].toString()` ?

Comment: `getCustomerName(Id)` returns a Object array. I'm lost on this earth.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the exceptions, the objects stored in your array are not of type String.

What you could do is use their `toString()` method :

```
row.setName(customers[0].toString()+" "+customers[1].toString());
```

Comment: So in the end my customer name will be `NameIdRoleAndWhatNot`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ If that's what the OP wants, that's what he/she will get. If the OP wants to get a specific property from the object, there is nothing stopping him/her from doing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
row.setName(((String) customers)[0]+" "+((String) customers)[1]);
```